# Strange disappearing <p> problem with Drupal 7

Tags: nodes, wysiwyg, input-formats

In CKEditor, source view, I see <p> tags around my paragraphs. That's great, makes sense. However when I view the node, the <p> tags are gone, replaced with <br> tags, thus killing the margins and cramming everything together. Re-editing the node brings the <p> tags back again in CKEditor.

I have tried changing the text format to disable "Convert line breaks into HTML", but of course that just removed *both* <p> and <br> tags, making one huge paragraph.

How do I prevent this and preserve the <p> tags?

Comment: Ah, I found it. In /admin/config/content/formats/filtered_html, I needed to add &lt;p> to the list of allowed HTML tags way at the bottom of the page. I'm not sure how/why this problem didn't show up previously...but this fixed it.

Comment: Josh, you can answer your own questions here. Put that as an answer, and you can mark it as the 'accepted' answer (so people can see this question has been answered), and then people who find your answer useful can upvote it, getting you points :)

Comment: I wasn't able to at the time, then I forgot about it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I found it. In /admin/config/content/formats/filtered_html, I needed to add <p> to the list of allowed HTML tags way at the bottom of the page. I'm not sure how/why this problem didn't show up previously...but this solved it.

Comment: and again i have to wait 9 hours...sigh...